# jQuery- change text color on button click

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I change the color of all paragraph tags on the page to green when a button is clicked?
I've started with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    button.click(function() {
 WHAT GOES HERE?     
    });
});
```

Comment: What you've already tried??

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.green{
   color: green;
}
</style>


$( "p" ).addClass( "green" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('button').on('click', function() { 
       $('p').css('color', 'green');
    }); 
});
```

You should start by reading the manual -> https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button selector').click(function() {
        $('p').attr('style','color: green;');
    });
});
```

This should do the trick